# How to use environment variable in #import c++ command?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, import, variables

nowadays I have this piece of code:

```
#import "C:\Users\Public\SoundLog\DLLs\ForPython\SoundLogDLL.tlb" named_guids
```

but I want to substitute the C:\Users\Public part by the %PUBLIC% environment variable.

How can I do this ?

Comment: #import is not C++, if you're using C++/CLI (of which I'm only passingly familiar) or something else, it would help to mention that.

Comment: It is used by native Visual C++ for importing COM type libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wise to store your projects in a common folder so that you can use relative paths.  The #import directive also searches files in the same folders where it looks for #include files.  In the IDE, you can add them with Project + Properties, C/C++, General, Additional Include Directories.

Comment: I have a lot of projects that work toogether. So, my common folder is that one that I specified in the question :D

Comment: @aF: you are getting a lot of unhelpful answers here.  Are you sure SO is the right place for you?

Comment: those answers allways help me to find the real one :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that your best option is to write `#import "SoundLogDLL.tlb" named_guids` in your code, and then use either the `INCLUDE` environment variable, the `/I` command-line switch to the compiler, or the `Additional Include Directories` IDE option to point the compiler in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do that.  You may either generate the file during a pre compile build step, or you can use the angle include `#import <filename> <attrs>` and have the location of it in your PATH.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more info, specifically Search Order for filename.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hard coded path in your code is never a good idea.
I recommend using a relative path and keeping your type library under the same folder structure as your code.

Then doing something like this:
 #import <SoundLogDLL.tlb> named_guids